# Magnetic field lines of a hollow spherical magnet

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

Assume that we have a magnetized spherical shell so that one half of this sphere is pole $S$ and the other is $N$. Whether or not the magnetic field is uniform inside the shell, I want to know if the *direction* of the field lines are always from $N$ to $S$ both inside and outside of the shell, and if the field lines are closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A piece of dipole magnetized matter has the known classical  magnetic dipole field on air around it and this field topology is invariant to the shape of the physical magnet. Meaning the magnetic lines of force having closed loops trajectory by convention going from N to S pole outside the magnet's bulk material and from S to N inside the magnet's bulk forming closed loops. This is also deduced from Gauss's law for magnetism,

∇ · B = 0 .

Ideally, a radially magnetized hollow sphere would induce B=0 zero magnetic field. But in your case you are asking about an axially magnetized hollow sphere with one hemisphere N and the other S.  The answer is nothing special. Gauss's law still holds and magnetic lines still going from N to S outside the sphere and S to N inside the hollow sphere cavity. Nevertheless, in this case most of the lines inside the hollow sphere cavity transverse the inner walls of the sphere thus most of the inside flux is concentrated there and H field of the magnet is stronger towards the inner walls. A few only lines are passing through the sphere's empty interior cavity.

How much? Depends of the thickness of of the walls of the hollow sphere axial magnet. A good reference can be found here [fig. 13](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F978-94-011-5478-9_87.pdf)

quote:
"Spherical magnet structure. The field in the central cavity is given by,

Bo =(4 Br/3)ln(r2/r1)

where Br is the magnetic remanence and r2 and rl are the outer and inner radii respectively." [1](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F978-94-011-5478-9_87.pdf)

We see from above that for very thin walls r2≈r1, Bo at the center of the cavity becomes practically zero.

Answer (score 2):

In a normal magnet, the field (which is the vector sum of billions of atomic dipole fields) enters at the south (seeking) pole, continues through the interior, exits at the north (seeking) pole, and loops around to form (always) closed loops. The field of a magnetized spherical shell would do the same.